# How to know the location of the first string when debugging WebSite in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web-crawler, reverse-engineering, v8

For example, when I'm debugging a website, I want to know where the JS code is located when the string "mywant" first appears during the runtime

such as , JS Code

```
line0: var a = "a"
line1: var b = "b"
line2: var c = a+b;
```

When the string "ab" appears, output the third line of code

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check the lines of code in JS by putting "Console.log()" in your desired line of code.
2. Set breakpoints in the JS code in your browser's "Developer Tools" window. for example in Chrome hit "F12" button. Then in the "Sources tab" you can find your JS file. by selecting the file, file content appears in the right panel and you can put breakpoints and use the "step next" and "step over" options to check your code line by line.

Comment: but if there are  large amount of code？